# AngularJS dynamic form value not picked up by angular on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a few form inputs on a page with angular model(s) attached but one of their values is set dynamically via a jquery call after some image upload has been performed.

```
  <input class="form-control ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required" id="name" ng-model="item.name" required="required" name="name" type="text" value="">

   <input class="form-control ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required" id="url" ng-model="item.url" required="required" name="url" type="text" value="">

   <input class="form-control" id="imgname" ng-model="item.imgname" required="required" name="imgname" type="text" value="">
```

The later input field is added via jquery.

```
   <input class="form-control" id="imgname" ng-model="item.imgname" required="required" name="imgname" type="text" value="">
```

The issue is then when i submit the form only the item.name and item.url are sent through and not the item.imgname.

my submit code:

```
   $scope.submitForm = function(store){
    ....
        $log.debug(store);
   };
```

I am adding the code to the form via:

```
  ...
  complete : function(imgname){
      JQ('#imgname').val(imgname);
  },...
```

How can i add the data and have the form pick it up on submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in fact after a few more goes at it and just checking my code, I first had to correct the input type as i was setting it to a URL not a text type thus it was always causing issues etc.

Anyway once that was sorted i then placed

```
       $scope.item = {};
```

Within my controller.

Then replaced the

```
     JQ('#imgname').val(imgname);
```

for the $scope value

```
    complete : function(imgname){

       $scope.item.img = imgname;

    }....
```

Then once the image was uploaded and then the form field populated as above inc. the other form details it the img field was submitted with the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set ng-model value via Jquery. Rather, you have to fill that scope named "item.imgname" somewhere in your controller like $scope.item.imgname="Hello"
and on Submit button you can get this whole model(item)... you'll have that value in item.imgname model for sure.

Comment: yeah! i thought as i tested it on submit and entered the value there statically just thought the model would take then value wehn set dynamically or not but thanks for the calrification